# TPoupMenu Radio Item uncheched while clicking same item

Tags: delphi

I have a poup-menu where i have two radio items.

```
procedure MySelector.CreatePopup;
begin
  FGroupingMenu := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
  FGroupingMenu.Name := 'FGroupingMenu';
  FGroupingMenu.OnPopup := GroupingMenuItemPopup;

  FmnuNameGroup := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  FmnuNameGroup.Name := 'mnuNameGroup';
  FmnuNameGroup.AutoCheck := True;
  FmnuNameGroup.Caption := '&Name Group';
  FmnuNameGroup.RadioItem := True;
  FmnuNameGroup.OnClick := GroupingMenuItemClick;
  FGroupingMenu.Items.Add(FmnuNameGroup);

  FmnuAge := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  FmnuAge .Name := 'mnuAge';
  FmnuAge .AutoCheck := True;
  FmnuAge .Caption := '&Age Group';
  FmnuAge .RadioItem := True;
  FmnuAge .OnClick := GroupingMenuItemClick;
  FGroupingMenu.Items.Add(FmnuAge);
end;
```

And the OnClick event is

```
procedure MySelector.GroupingMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FmnuNameGroup.Checked then
    grp:= sgName
  else if FmnuAge .Checked then
    grp := sgAge
  else
    Assert(False, 'MySelector.GroupingMenuItemClick: Unknown MenuItem');
end;
```

The problem is if initially name group is selected and if i click the same item again, OnClick event is called and Name group now becomes unselected and since none of the item is checked it is crashing.

Is there anyway to prevent menu item from unchecking if i select the selected item again or is there any way to check in onclick whether the Sender is already selected item?

Another solution i thought is to make AutoCheck false and have the OnClick event handler like below

```
procedure MySelector.GroupingMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  mnuItem : TMenuItem;
begin   

  mnuItem := sender as TMenuItem;
  if mnuItem.Name =  'mnuNameGroup' then
  begin
   grp:= sgName
   FmnuNameGroup.Checked := true;
  end
  else if mnuItem.Name =  'mnuAge' then
  begin
   grp := sgAge
   FmnuAge.Checked := true;
  end 
  else
   Assert(False, 'MySelector.GroupingMenuItemClick: Unknown MenuItem');
end;
```

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: No, you have to do it manually like you're doing. Menu items neither behave like a radio group nor like tool buttons that have AllowAllUp which you can set to False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the following changes:

1. Leave `AutoCheck` as `False`.
2. Set a `GroupIndex` for these two items. For example, set `GroupIndex` to `1` for both items. This makes them part of the same group and no more than one of the group can be checked at any instance.
3. Change the `OnClick` event handler to be like this:

```
procedure MySelector.GroupingMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TMenuItem).Checked := True;
  // any other logic goes here
end;
```

When you click on an item, it will be checked, and all other members of that group are unchecked. Assuming that you make one of the items checked before you show the menu, you will always have exactly one checked member of the group.